# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>

Tags: selenium

Getting Null pointer exception when I am working with Actions class in the POM.

```
public class Homepage_purchase {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"menu-item-2822\"]") WebElement Purc_Form;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"menu-item-2824\"]") WebElement Purc_Form2;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"menu-item-2843\"]") WebElement Purc_Form6;

    public Homepage_purchase(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void Purchaseform_1() {

    Actions act=new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(Purc_Form).build().perform();
    act.moveToElement(Purc_Form2).build().perform();
    act.moveToElement(Purc_Form6).build().perform();
    Purc_Form6.click();
}
}

public class baseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public void browserLaunch(String Browser_is) {

        if(Browser_is.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\veerendra\\Downloads\\python software\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(Browser_is.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\veerendra\\Downloads\\python software\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        }
    public void Url_selection(String URL,int waitime) {

        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}


public class Homepage_mouseover extends baseTest {

    Homepage_purchase HomePurchase;

    @BeforeClass
    public void test() {
        Homepage_mouseover ob=new Homepage_mouseover();
        ob.browserLaunch("chrome");
        ob.Url_selection("http://www.globalsqa.com/", 60);  
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() throws Exception  {
        HomePurchase=new Homepage_purchase(driver);
        System.out.println("1111");
        HomePurchase.Purchaseform_1();
        System.out.println("2222");

    }
```

> FAILED: Test1 java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.(Actions.java:44)  at
>   UI_Webelements_Homescreen.Homepage_purchase.Purchaseform_1(Homepage_purchase.java:28)
>     at TestPackages.Homepage_mouseover.Test1(Homepage_mouseover.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate your page object BEFORE your driver:

```
    Homepage_mouseover ob=new Homepage_mouseover();
    ob.browserLaunch("chrome");
    ob.Url_selection("http://www.globalsqa.com/", 60);
```

Move the first line to the third, AND pass the driver as a parameter.

```
    ob.browserLaunch("chrome");
    ob.Url_selection("http://www.globalsqa.com/", 60);  
    Homepage_mouseover ob=new Homepage_mouseover(driver);
```

I'm not sure why the compiler is not catching that your page object call is missing the driver parameter.

Also, a heads-up warning: If you're current on your Selenium and Chrome versions, the maximize will fail - search for the correct method to maximize using options.

Comment: i tried like below.directly called base class method without creating object...it is working fine now.

    @BeforeClass
    public void test() {
        browserLaunch("chrome");
        Url_selection("http://www.globalsqa.com/", 60);

Answer (score 0):

i tried like below.directly called base class method without creating object...it is working fine now.

```
@BeforeClass
public void test() {
    browserLaunch("chrome");
    Url_selection("http://www.globalsqa.com/", 60);
```